# Keep div visible in the middle of the window while scrolling down and fade out after reaching a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to do a simple parallax effect with jQuery and CSS.

I have 2 long divs, one is `2000px` and the other is `1000px` each one of those divs have a child div with text inside.

I would like to have these child divs to be centered in the middle of the visible window (not the div which is `2000px` high, just the visible window) and to stay centered and in the middle while I scroll down, then fade out at a certain point before reaching the next div.

At the moment, I managed to create the html layout and the css, and made the divs to fade out on click using jQuery.

But I am unable to center them in the middle of the window and keep them fixed while I scroll down and fade them out before reaching the next div.

Maybe I can use Waypoint.js to trigger events at certain points in the scroll but how do I keep the div centered and visible to achieve the parallax effect?

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/fmub10pv/4/

**EDIT** Are there any plugins (with demo) that can achieve what I want?

**EDIT 2** The desired effect is something like this http://davegamache.com/parallax/

HTML

```
<div class="container" id="firstContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div id="firstDiv" class="animate text-center">
                <h1>First Div</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="secondContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <div id="secondDiv" class="animate text-center">
                <h1>Second Div</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
        background-color: #16191b;
        color: white;
    }
    #firstContainer {
        height: 2000px;
        margin-top: 80px;
        background: darkslategrey;
    }
    #secondContainer {
        height: 1000px;
        background: darkslateblue;
    }
    .animate {
        padding: 20px;
        background: mediumseagreen;
    }
    #firstDiv {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
    #secondDiv {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var total = winHeight - current;

    $('#firstDiv').on('click', function() {
       if ($('#firstDiv').css('opacity') == 0) $('#firstDiv').css('opacity', 1);
       else $('#firstDiv').css('opacity', 0);
    });

    $('#secondDiv').on('click', function() {
       if ($('#secondDiv').css('opacity') == 0) $('#secondDiv').css('opacity', 1);
       else $('#secondDiv').css('opacity', 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will check if you've passed a certain waypoint and update the opacity for how much further you scroll thereafter.

Do you mind jQuery?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  waypoint = 400

  if ($(document).scrollTop() > waypoint) {
    alpha = 1 - (($(document).scrollTop() - waypoint) / 260) // 260 is an arbitrary number, the size determines how quickly it will fade out (reach 0)
  } else {
    alpha = 1
  }

  $("#fade").css({
    "opacity": alpha
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mqk9xux6/

Comment: This is the closest to what I want to achieve. may I trouble you and ask you to add a second div that will appear once the first div fades out?

Answer (score 0):

Add `fade-in` class to the first div initially

```
<div id="firstDiv" class="animate text-center fade-in">
```

To center the divs

```
#firstDiv,
#secondDiv {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin : 0 auto;
  height : 500px;
  width : 500px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  opacity:0;
}
```

To fade them out on scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
 var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(scrollPos >= 2000) 
  $("#firstDiv").removeClass("fade-in");
 if(scrollPos >= 2200)
  $("#secondDiv").addClass("fade-in");
}).scroll();
```

Comment: Feel free to change the size of the divs. The script merely fades out the first div at scroll position 2000, height of the first parent.

Comment: The second div now sits on top of the first div right from the start. The second div should stay at the bottom of the page until I reach it while scrolling down. And the fadeout doesn't work, it merely disappears.

Comment: Oops , forgot to hide it

Comment: Edited my answer. Now initially the second div will be hidden and fades in after 200px scroll down after the first div fades out to the same position.

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't work at all. The first div is supposed to fade out before the second Div comes into view. And you've set the second div to `display: none`

Comment: The first div fades out at 2000px and the second div fades in at 2200px. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: This is just a demo assuming there are no elements before the two parent divs. If so you'll have to takr into consideration their scrollTops

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a class that makes use of the `fixed` position, which then gets applied to the target element based on scroll offset. Note that the `fixed` position is not a block-level element, so you will need to give it a width of `95%` as well to match the original design:

CSS:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 95%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 2000) {
    $('#firstDiv').removeClass('fixed');
  } else if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 2000) {
    $('#firstDiv').addClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

In the above example, I've used an offset of `2000px`. This means that the first DIV will stay fixed until it overlaps exactly with the second DIV. Scrolling up the page, the first DIV will stay fixed again. Hopefully this is the sort of effect you're looking for.

I've created a fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/urg3es92/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I reset the offset to `1500` so now the first div disappears before reaching the second div. but it doesn't fade out the way I've had it set up in the original jsfiddle. Are there any plugins that can achieve what I want?